# Create a log everytime When methods in an interface class are called

Tags: asp.net, logging

I want to update a log file(txt) everytime when methods in a an interface class are called?
Is there any way to do this other than writing code in every method to create log?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 30 mins. you'll have to implement the logging code somewhere so you have to create another abstraction for your code. thus an abstract class is needed. i think. this is very quick and dirty.

```
public interface IService<T>
{
    List<T> GetAll();
    bool Add(T obj);
}
```

then you'll need the abstract class where you'll need to implement your logging routine

```
public abstract class Service<T> : IService<T>
{
    private void log()
    {
        /// TODO : do log routine here
    }

    public bool Add(T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            log();
            return AddWithLogging(obj);
        }
        finally
        {
            log();
        }         
    }

    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            log();
            return GetAllWithLog();
        }
        finally
        {
            log();
        }  
    }

    protected abstract List<T> GetAllWithLog();
    protected abstract bool AddWithLogging(T obj);
}
```

as for your concrete classes

```
public class EmployeeService : Service<Employee>
{
    protected override List<Employee> GetAllWithLog()
    {            
        return new List<Employee>() { new Employee() { Id = 0, Name = "test" } };
    }

    protected override bool AddWithLogging(Employee obj)
    {
        /// TODO : do add logic here
        return true;
    }
}

public class CompanyService : Service<Company>
{
    protected override List<Company> GetAllWithLog()
    {
        return new List<Company>() { new Company() { Id = 0, Name = "test" } };
    }

    protected override bool AddWithLogging(Company obj)
    {
        /// TODO : do add logic here
        return true;
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then on your implementation you can just..

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IService<Employee> employee = new EmployeeService();
        List<Employee> employees = employee.GetAll();

        foreach (var item in employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

        IService<Company> company = new CompanyService();
        List<Company> companies = company.GetAll();

        foreach (var item in companies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your time micheal.. i shall now try this one out..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use Aspect Oriented Programming to achieve that.  Read http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net

Comment: I am sorry, i am a asp.net newbie can you provide me a some more direct example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant class (instead of interface)
Two options I can think of:

Implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged** which is in lines of writing code in every method

**or**

to adopt on of the **AOP** frameworks in the article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AOP_Frameworks_Rating.aspx if that is not a major leap

Comment: Can you provide me a more direct example?

Comment: Link for INotifyPropertyChanged: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx for the other AOP frameworks, the respective sites have good examples.